# Is it possible to replace the RTE in TYPO3?

Tags: typo3, typo3-tca

I found a better JS RTE out there and would like to know how to replace the TYPO3 default with the one I found. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything stating how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not easily possible without "loosing" many TYPO3 features, because the `rtehtmlarea` highly integrated into TYPO3.
Especially the link handling is custom, so you would have to write special support to make this work.

A possible replacement is [`tinemce_rte`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tinymce_rte). It works fairly well, but it does a little more than just replacing the editor with `tinymce`, e.g. it also adds custom linkhandler support. You can look into this extension if you really want to do this work.

Comment: the tiny mce rte is the js rte I found but I wasn't aware it had an extension. Thx

Comment: I did this too, but waiting each major version for an extension update made me switch back to the integrated editor. It just works better if you use the tested one.

Answer (score 1):

You can download tinyrte or ask in tinyrte forum how to replace htmlarea. Here is the download link: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/tinyrte.

Comment: TYPO3 uses a completely custom RTE that has almost nothing in common with the original `htmlarea`. It is not possible just replace this editor, because it implements a lot of special TYPO3 features, like complex rules on which markup is accepted and TYPO3 link element handling.

Comment: @pgampe: Yes but why makes things complicated? I was the author of the first linkhandler extension!!!???

Comment: As suggested by pgampe, the tinymce_rte extension is better than the tinymce extension. It works good in many projects and fits at least the most needs.

Comment: It does not support all TYPO3 features. And I removed the downvote again after I wrote the comment.

Comment: Well tbh for what I need the tiny MCE with its current release has everything, whether it works well enough with other extensions remains to be seen but for now it does the exact job I need it to do.